# want to back-burner Guantanamo issues

Tags: phrase-usage

"Back burner" is a noun phrase, but here the author appears to have used it as a verb phrase.  Does it serve here as a verb?

> The New York Times Retweeted
> Carol Rosenberg:

> NEW: The Biden team may **want to back-burner Guantanamo issues** while it focuses on vaccinating the nation, shoring up the economy and mending foreign relations. But a moment of reckoning is coming on what to do about its failing, Camp 7 of ex-CIA prisoners.

Comment: Yes: it 's a compound verb. It has a subject, "Biden team" and an object, "Guantanamo issues". I haven't come across it in BrE, so perhaps it's mainly found in AmE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is being used as a verb here, shorthand for "to place on the back burner", that is "to reduce the priority of". This way of converting nouns or noun phrases to verbs, often by omitting an implied verb, is now common in English usage, indeed it is often called "verbing nouns" which is an example of its own meaning.

Comment: I would call it a compound verb rather than a verb phrase. The latter term implies that it's a syntactic construction, which it isn't.

Comment: Actually, the term ***verbification*** is [far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=verbing+nouns%2Cverbing+noun%2Cverbification&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cverbing%20nouns%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cverbification%3B%2Cc0) than "verbing nouns".

Comment: @FumbleFingers  An [apples to apples comparison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=verbing%2C+verbification&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cverbing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cverbification%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cverbing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cverbification%3B%2Cc0) shows that "verbing" is far more common than is "verbificartion". But both terms are widely used, indicating thst the process is common.

Comment: @BillJ Correction made

Comment: A [***same variety** of apples to apples*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=verbing+of+nouns%2Cverbification+of+nouns&year_start=1920&year_end=2010&corpus=26&smoothing=3) comparison shows that ***verbification** of nouns* was actually more common than ***verbing*** back in the 80s. I'm just a couple of decades behind the times!